# How to set radio buttons in a nested group box as a same group with radio buttons outside of that group box

Tags: c#, winforms, radio-button

I have winform application (.NET 4.0)

Is there any way to manually set a group of radio buttons?

I have four radio buttons, two of them inside of a group box and the other two outside of that box. How can I set all of them to the same group?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This might have been answered in another post, it sounds the same:

[Grouping Windows Forms Radiobuttons with different parent controls in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627314/grouping-windows-forms-radiobuttons-with-different-parent-controls-in-c-sharp)

This was the accepted solution:

> I'm afraid you'll have to handle this manually... It's not so bad
>   actually, you can probably just store all the RadioButton in a list,
>   and use a single event handler for all of them:
>
> ```
> private List<RadioButton> _radioButtonGroup = new List<RadioButton>();
> private void radioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
> {
>     RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)sender;
>     if (rb.Checked)
>     {
>         foreach(RadioButton other in _radioButtonGroup)
>         {
>             if (other == rb)
>             {
>                 continue;
>             }
>             other.Checked = false;
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Edit:  Here's another question asking the same thing:
[Radiobuttons as a group in different panels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727415/radiobuttons-as-a-group-in-different-panels)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is possible in WinForms.

According to the docs:

> All RadioButton controls in a given container, such as a Form, constitute a group.

You could create the class yourself though

```
public class ButtonGroup {
   private IList<RadioButton> radiogroup;

   public ButtonGroup(IEnumerable<RadioButton> selection) {
      radiogroup = new List<RadioButton>(selection);
      foreach (RadioButton item in selection) {
          item.CheckedChanged += uncheckOthers;
      }
   }

   private void uncheckOthers(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      if (((RadioButton)sender).Checked) {
        foreach (RadioButton item in radiogroup) {
          if (item != sender) { item.Checked = false; }
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

GroupName is property used in Web.UI.RadioButton to group a set of radio butons as one unit. All radiobuttons with same GroupName value will form a group.

This functionality however is not available in winforms.

So the only way to group radiobuttons in winforms will be to keep them together in the same container (generally a groupbox).

Comment: @nawfal it is because in the previous post poster was asking for Groupname property which is not availabe in winform. and the whole world including you did not answer it.

Comment: previous post? which previous post? This page is to have answers for the question asked here! There is nothing OP wants by a groupname, instead OP wants a way to group radiobuttons so that it exhibit the standard behaviour. He got an answer, which means he got an answer. To say something is impossible when that wasn't the requirement is meaningless.

Comment: I still stand by my answer and it also clarifies why the OP could not find GroupName property. Refer to the answer posted by @iefpw and the comments by OP. My answer is relevant or not let people decide.

Comment: Understand the point deb, where did OP mention he cant find a groupName? If he mentions so clearly that its winforms and his requirement (which deals no way with group name), why post an **answer** which is abt webforms? it should be a comment at best to help the user more. Someone else posting an answer (by mistake clearly, unlike u) wouldnt come to your support.

Comment: And over all your answer which says "there is no way other than putting them in a container" is wrong. Either way your answer is invalid here. Its so **astonishing** that u make that point hours after members already giving valid answer. Im just asking to learn etiquette followed here at SO

Comment: "where did OP mention he cant find a groupName?.." Read the comment to the answer provided by @iefpw. You have asked this question twice without even reading what i said. And plz stop worrying about me and my posts and my etiquetes. I can live with mine

Comment: Nope, I read it. My question is where has the OP asked that **in the question?** That's the intent, the purport. Its clear. All his requirement is to get a workin solution for a group of dispersed radiobuttons. Just because some1 has answered a nonrelevant answer doesn't mean OP is looking for that. I mean groupname per say wasn't OP's issue!

Comment: if an answer which wouldnt work in this case (the answer from iepfw) has been posted by some1, then the correction for it is another comment, not an answer. _Since after all the answer by iepfw was not at all related to the question in this context_. **The OP put forward that comment because someone has posted an incorrect answer. Which doesnt mean thats the part of the question. The OP was just curious to know**. And still your comment "there is no working way out" doesnt hold water, that too after receiving working solutions. I hope u carry something forward from this chat. No offense bud..

Answer (score -1):

There is a property called "validation" group or something like that that groups all the controls into one validation. Only one of them is checked only. Other ones uncheck.

Comment: I am sorry I can't find such a property. You don't need to explain everything but one reference would suffice.

Comment: It is availabe in webforms not in winforms.

Comment: and It is not "Validation" group, it is "GroupName" property by the way