# C# - If A Radiobutton Selected In GroupBox, Unselect Other Radiobuttons In Other GroupBoxes

Tags: c#, winforms, radio-button, groupbox

I have 11 GroupBoxes and 40 RadioButton in my project. I wanna make when I select a RadioButton in a GroupBox, the other RadioButtons in other GroupBoxes unselect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set radio buttons in a nested group box as a same group with radio buttons outside of that group box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073692/how-to-set-radio-buttons-in-a-nested-group-box-as-a-same-group-with-radio-button)

Comment: That sounds like bad design UI to me.  You group radio buttons because they work together.

Comment: One radio button in a Group Box always is selected.  You could have a main Groupbox and depending on which button is selected you can enable/disable the other Groupboxes so a user can only select buttons in the enabled Groupboxes.

Comment: @Sinatr it's not duplicate, answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can **recursively search** the Form for all RadioButtons, then wire them up and use code like suggested in the linked question from the comments.

It might look something like:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        FindRadioButtons(this);
    }

    private List<RadioButton> RadioButtons = new List<RadioButton>();

    private void FindRadioButtons(Control curControl)
    {
        foreach(Control subControl in curControl.Controls)
        {
            if (subControl is RadioButton)
            {
                RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)subControl;
                rb.CheckedChanged += Rb_CheckedChanged;
                RadioButtons.Add(rb);
            }
            else if(subControl.HasChildren)
            {
                FindRadioButtons(subControl);
            }
        }
    }

    private void Rb_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButton source = (RadioButton)sender;
        if (source.Checked)
        {
            RadioButtons.Where(rb => rb != source).ToList().ForEach(rb => rb.Checked = false);
        }          
    }

}
```